# Error "Undefined property:" en php

Tags: php, mysql, mvc

> ( ! ) Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$documentoP in
>   C:\wamp64\www\mathematchy\mathematchy\controller\logincontroller.php
>   on line 48

Presento este error cuando trate de hacer otro login en mi página `(localhost)`.

Este es mi código:

```
public function profes(){


      foreach ($this->model->verificar_credencialesprofes($_REQUEST['documentoP'],$_REQUEST['contrasenaP']) as $key) {

      }

      if(($_POST['documentoP']==$key->documentoP)&&($_POST['contrasenaP']==$key->contrasenaP)){

        $nuevo=new security();
        $nuevo->profes($key->usuarioP,$key->documentoP);

        $_SESSION['nombre']=$key->usuarioP;

        /*header('location: http://localhost/iniciodesesion/?clase=admin&metodo=profes');
      */}
      /*else{
        echo "<script> alert('El usuario o la contraseña son incorrectas');window.history.go(-1);</script>";



      }*/


    }
```

PD: El script lo tengo comentado para visualizar el error. Uso wamp y MySql. Mi proyecto lo manejo en MVC.

Comment: Creo que debes poner el if dentro de tu foreach, ya que lo cierras y posteriormente pones tu if

Comment: No estoy seguro de que con esa sintaxis `$key` esté disponible fuera del foreach. Me imagino que sí, aunque lo que quedará disponible será el último valor del foreach. Lo que está provocando el error es que `$key` no tiene la propiedad `documentoP`. Prueba haciendo un `var_dump` de $key antes de tu `if`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error puede ser debido a que le estás pasando dos variables a la función profes, pero tienes declarada la función sin variables.

```
public function profes(){

  profes($key->usuarioP,$key->documentoP);

}
```

> (necesitaria ver la linea 48 del archivo logincontroller.php)